# Is my site hitted by crawler

Tags: internet-explorer, http, browser, web-crawler

I have created my site, Let say abc.com and I used this site to shared via facebook, twitter and email with some query strings.
While click on this link from facebook, twitter or email, the website abc.com logs website view activity.

while publishing the adv on facebook and twitter, abc.com receives a hit from crawler and logs websiteview activity. So I have written this code to check iscrawler request. 
Now issue is this code is not working for Internet explorer. (Request.UrlReferrer is null)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check whether the request via Crawl request / email / social network
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool isCrawlerRequest()
    {
        try{

        //any mannual click from facebook or twitter sends URLReferrer while crawlers do not send URLReferrer. 
        //Therefore if URLReferrer is missing then we can consider it a crawller. But Manual click from mail boxes also do not send URLReferer though they do have Query String Param "Source= email". So if URLReferrer and Utm_Source both are missing, we are assuming that it is a crawller.
        //Also, any correct UserAgent would not contain ".com", "www.", "http:". Only crawller User agents contain such text
        bool urlReferrer = false;
        if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString))
                urlReferrer = true;

        if (urlReferrer || (!urlReferrer && (string.Equals(Source, "email", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                && !UIHelper.Contains(Request.UserAgent, ".com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && !UIHelper.Contains(Request.UserAgent, "www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && !UIHelper.Contains(Request.UserAgent, "https:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && !UIHelper.Contains(Request.UserAgent, "http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Well, a missing referrer header simply is not a valid test to decide some client is a crawler. You chose an approach that does not lead to a solution. Sorry.

Comment: What should be the appropriate solution for this? I googled for solution but not getting any good solution.

Comment: There simply is no reliable way to tell a "crawler" apart from a "normal" client. Simply because a crawler _is_ a normal web client. You can try to implement all sorts of detection strategies, but you will never get a reliable solution. Best bet is to evaluate how a crawler or robot calls itself in requests, so compare that to a list of names of known robots. That way you can at least detect _known_ robots in a decent manner. You will _never_ be able to detect robots (or "crawlers") that do not want to be detected.